# Laravel send json date not as a string

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

Right now I send the date like this (in Laravel5.2):

```
'BirthDate'         => $employee->BirthDate,
```

result:

```
“2016-05-10"
```

But the json result in postman should be this:

```
2016-05-10
```

How could I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `strtotime()`

```
$time = strtotime($employee->BirthDate);
'BirthDate' => date('Y-m-d',$time);
```

Please refer to [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) function at php.net